# Flash builder (Flex) - hide UI element

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flash-builder

Hey, how can I hide an element in Flash Builder? I can do visible=false but the element is still there (other buttons are not centered). I'm looking for display:none style property.

```
<mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center">
   <mx:Button id="publishButton" label="Start" />
   <mx:Button label="Stop" visible="false" />
</mx:HBox>
```

Thx!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

visible="false" includeInLayout="false", they should be used together.